# ionic 3 alert button handler async issue

Tags: http, asynchronous, ionic-framework, ionic3, local-storage

I am currently applying code on an error from an http.post call.

```ts
this.http.post('api here', {'email':this.username})
.subscribe(response => {
    if(response === true){
        localStorage.setItem('Username', this.username);
        this.navCtrl.push(Page_1);
},
(error) => {
    if(error == '404'){
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title:'',
            message:'',
            buttons: [
                 {
                     text:'no',
                     handler: () => {
                         console.log('no clicked');
                     }
                 },
                 {
                     test:'yes',
                     handler: () => {
                         localStorage.setItem('Register_User', 
                         this.username);
                         this.navCtrl.push(Page_2);
                     }
                 }
                    ]
         });
         alert.present();
     }}
})
```

So the problem i am having above, is that when i get a 404 error from the server and I want to direct them to page 2, it does not set the local storage register_username. My guess is, that this is an async thing, and its pushing to the page before it can set the storage. How do i resolve this?

Comment: then make a timeout to push to next page, save in localstorage and the go the page `setTimeout(() => {
         this.navCtrl.push(Page_2);
      },1500);`

Comment: you did fine in pushing the page after setting data, localstorage is not asynchronous, i think the issue is with your handling of http post.

Answer (score 0):

If `localStorage.setItem` is **Promise**, then

```
handler: () => {
  localStorage.setItem('Register_User', this.username)
    .then(()=>{this.navCtrl.push(Page_2);})
}
```